# Django Admin - Dynamic value for a list of tabular inline foreign key fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I have three models:

```
class Foo (models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default = date.today)

class Bar (models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    another = models.ForeignKey(AnotherClass) #this class is important
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class AnotherClass (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Now I want to add/change instances of Foo+Bar's in a tabular inline way. The key is that each Bar instance is the reference of an amount of AnotherClass instance, and each Foo instance must have reference of all the AnotherClass in the system.

So if I have a list of AnotherClass's instances

```
AnotherClass1
AnotherClass2
AnotherClass3
AnotherClass4
```

The Foo add/change admin page should be something like this

```
Add Foo!
--------------------------------------------

date = (datePicker)

Pretty Bar TabularInline
--------------------------------------------
AnotherClass1.name        amount = intPicker
AnotherClass2.name        amount = intPicker
AnotherClass3.name        amount = intPicker
AnotherClass4.name        amount = intPicker
```

where AnotherClassX.name is not editable, shows only the name of the AnotherClass instances.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar using TabularInline from django.contrib.admin. Below is an example. I created admin.py in the same Django app ('test_app') as models.py just to keep the Admin site stuff separate from the model code.

```
### models.py ###
from django.db import models
from datetime import date

class Foo (models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default = date.today)

class AnotherClass (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Bar (models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    another = models.ForeignKey(AnotherClass) #this class is important
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('foo', 'another'),)

### admin.py ###
from test_app.models import Foo, Bar, AnotherClass
from django.contrib import admin

class BarsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Bar

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (BarsInline,)

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
admin.site.register(Bar)
admin.site.register(AnotherClass)
```

This will add the capability to add or modify multiple Bar relationships when creating or editing a Foo instance. Note that the AnotherClass choices are drop-down menus, but the  AnotherClass.name field is not editable.

One issue to be aware of is the model schema you describe allows the same AnotherClass instance to be associated with a Foo (via Bar) multiple times. This may or may not be what you want. To prevent multiple relationships between an AnotherClass instance and a Foo instance use the Meta option 'unique_together' in the Bar model, which is used in the example code above. If you want to allow this behavior, simply remove this Meta class option.

Comment: I tried this but I don't want the user to pick, by the drop-down menu, all the AnotherClass instances every time, but they all appear, without have to choose them, every time the user wants to add/change a Foo instance. I have to say that I didn't know the 'unique_together' property and I think it's very useful, but the other part I'm afraid is imposible to do only with the admin Django app.